Errors like "Missing case type defintion" and "Invalid case type name" on upgrade to 5.75.0
I'm testing an upgrade from 5.71.2 to 5.75.0, and I see several red flagged errors in the System Status page. For example,
!Missing case type definition
Unable to locate xml file for Case Type "Civil & Political".
!Invalid case type name
Case Type "Civil & Political" has invalid characters in the internal machine name (Civil & Political). Only letters, numbers, and underscore are allowed.
Similar errors are displayed for Case Type "Economic, Social & Cultural" and Case Type "Gender Issues". I don't use CiviCase so neither the component nor the extension for CiviCase are installed. This is on Wordpress 6.5.5.  Any help appreciated.

One possibility is you used to have civicase and stored xml files in the main tree, which is allowed but then on upgrade they can get deleted.
But I agree it's odd that this check is even happening if you don't have civicase enabled. Are you sure the upgrade is configured to point at the right database?
Since you're not using it, and assuming you don't care about any old cases that might be in the database, you could just truncate civicrm_case_type in mysql.

Yes the upgrade is pointing to the right database. It's a copy of production that is refreshed periodically using a script. It's possible that someone turned on CiviCase briefly as an experiment at some point, I don't know. I guess that would explain it. Anyway, truncating civicrm_case_type fixed the problem, so I will mark this as solved. Thanks!

Last thought: the 5.75 upgrade must be doing something new with cases, since this never happened before. It would be better if the upgrade script tested for civicase being enabled before trying to access the case data.

There's nothing in the (core) upgrade from 5.71 to 5.75 that touches this. The reason I thought it might be looking at the wrong database is because it only runs the check if civicase is enabled so that's still a bit confusing.

Noting someone else has reported similar: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/5337

There's a patch available now: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/30636/files

Thank you for reporting this - the issue will be resolved in 5.75.1+
